# Relacionamento entre tabelas de arquivos diferentes

Tags: sql, sqlite

No Access é possível fazer relacionamento entre tabelas que estão em bancos (arquivos) diferentes, esse recurso é chama no Access de vinculação de tabelas. Ou seja, posso ter uma tabela chamada `CLIENTE` em um arquivo `.accdb` e relacionar ela com uma tabela chamada `ENDERECOS` que está em outro `arquivo.accdb`. Isso é útil para minimizar os problemas de concorrência e “burlar” o limite de 2GB por arquivo que o Access tem.

Existe algum parecido no SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível sim, mas não recomendável porque perde a capacidade de transação e concorrência, então se acha que vai melhorar a concorrência está fazendo o oposto.

Note que eu falei em relacionar as tabelas, não usar uma chave estrangeira nela, você não pode usar uma chave estrangeira que não existe no banco de dados, se o Access permite é só mais um motivo para nunca usá-lo, ele não valida coisas básicas. Um relacionamento pode ocorrer sem chave estrangeira.

Só lembrando que o SQLite tem um limite absurdamente maior então não tem porque manter os dados em arquivos separados.

Veja [`ATTACH`](https://sqlite.org/lang_attach.html).

Comment: Após postar a pergunta continuei pesquisando, e encontrei um [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289837/foreign-key-in-main-database-referencing-attached-database) afirmando que não seria possível, que o recurso de ATTACH não serviria para criar chaves estrangeiras entra as tabelas por exemplo.

Comment: A sua pergunta diz sobre relacionamento não sobre chave estrangeira.